# python: performance improvement for file reads?

Tags: python, performance

If I have a python module that at the start of the time (not in a function or class) reads a value from a file, does that get executed every time? or does the pyc file read the value in a stores the value in the compiled file?

Comment: You wouldn't actually want the `.pyc` file to store the file contents, because precompiled Python files persist indefinitely (they are only regenerated when the corresponding source code is changed). Python would have no way of knowing whether the file had changed since it had been read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of using `reload`, a module will only be imported and executed once, the first time your program imports it. Further imports of the same module just bind the existing name in the scope where the import happens, so the read will only be done once.

If you're asking whether the compilation step reads the file and embeds it in the `.pyc`, then no. The code isn't run at all at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this gets executed every time the module is loaded.